# android inapp billing sku depreced

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am using the Google in-app purchase feature in my application.

Since I encountered the "setSkuDetails" deprecation error, I tried to update the codes, but unfortunately, I couldn't find a solution despite working on it for many hours.

I am using Billing v5 version, and I am waiting for your assistance.

```
public class MainActivity3 extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String SKU_1 = "test.inapp.inap1";
    private static final String SKU_5 = "test.sub.inap5";

    private LinearLayout button;
    private TextView textView;

    private BillingClient mBillingClient;
    private Map<String, SkuDetails> mSkuDetailsMap = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.buycoin_fragment);

        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);

        button = findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                launchBilling(SKU_1);
            }
        });

        setupBilling();

    }

    private void setupBilling() {
        mBillingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(this)
                .enablePendingPurchases()
                .setListener(new PurchasesUpdatedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPurchasesUpdated(BillingResult billingResult, @Nullable List<Purchase> purchases) {
                        if (purchases != null) {
                            if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK && purchases != null) {
                                for (Purchase purchase : purchases) {
                                    try {
                                        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(purchase.getOriginalJson());
                                        //consume(purchase.getPurchaseToken(), purchase.getDeveloperPayload(), obj.getString("productId"));
                                        Log.e("Billing", obj.toString());
                                    } catch (Throwable t) {
                                        Log.e("Billing", "Could not parse malformed JSON: \"" + purchase.toString() + "\"");
                                    }
                                }
                            } else if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.USER_CANCELED) {
                                // Handle an error caused by a user cancelling the purchase flow.
                            } else {
                                // Handle any other error codes.
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })
                .build();

        mBillingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBillingSetupFinished(BillingResult billingResult) {
                if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                    querySkuDetails();
                    Log.e("onBillingSetupFinished", "WORKS");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
                Log.e("onBillingSetupFinished", "NOT WORKS");
            }
        });
    }

    private void querySkuDetails() {

        SkuDetailsParams.Builder skuDetailsParamsBuilder = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder();
        List<String> skuList = new ArrayList<>();
        skuList.add(SKU_1);
        skuList.add(SKU_5);

        skuDetailsParamsBuilder.setSkusList(skuList).setType(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP);
        mBillingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(skuDetailsParamsBuilder.build(), new SkuDetailsResponseListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSkuDetailsResponse(BillingResult billingResult, List<SkuDetails> skuDetailsList) {

                if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {

                    if (skuDetailsList != null) {

                        for (SkuDetails skuDetails : skuDetailsList) {

                            mSkuDetailsMap.put(skuDetails.getSku(), skuDetails);

                            textView.setText(skuDetails.getPrice());
                        }


                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void launchBilling(String skuId) {

        BillingFlowParams billingFlowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                .setSkuDetails(mSkuDetailsMap.get(skuId))
                .build();
        mBillingClient.launchBillingFlow(this, billingFlowParams);
    }

}
```